# How to tell which Button has been clicked, when it's generated dynamically? (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a SearchResultsViewModel with observable collection of recipe class and a command to show a recipe:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Recipe> _searchedRecipes;
    public ObservableCollection<Recipe> SearchedRecipes
    {
        get
        {
            return _searchedRecipes;
        }
        set
        {
            _searchedRecipes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Show Recipe Command

    public ICommand ShowRecipeCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(() => 
    ExecuteShowRecipeCommand()); } }

    public void ExecuteShowRecipeCommand()
    {
        _locator.Main.CurrentViewModel = new DisplayRecipeViewModel();
    }
    #endregion
```

Another ViewModel performs a query and passes results in the constructor of this ViewModel.
In XAML part of the SearchResultsViewModel, results are presented as Buttons dynamically. Each Recipe is a Button with it's name as content:

```
     <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path = SearchedRecipes}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Command="{Binding ShowRecipeCommand}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
```

I want ShowRecipeCommand to create new DisplayRecipeViewModel with a View bound to it, displaying the properties of Recipe that was clicked but I don't know how
to tell which Button was clicked.
Is it possible to do this without code behind ??

Comment: Pass whatever you need to via `CommandParameter` ? I'm not sure if your `RelayCommand` implementation supports the scenario (it should) but in worst case just implement the `ICommand` yourself.

Comment: Move the command property to the Recipe class?

Comment: @mm8 Is it ok to do this when Model is generated from database?

Comment: A class is not "generated from a database". It might be generated by an ORM such as Entity Framework. In this case you could create another partial class where you define the command.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just move the command property to the `Recipe` class. Then each `Button` (or rather each data object that is represented by a `Button`) has its own command and you always know which one that was clicked.

If the `Recipe` class is auto-generated by some ORM such as for example Entity Framework, you could create another partial class where you define the command property.